# laravel filter only nested condition

Tags: php, laravel

I want to filter **ONLY** nested values in **dealTransactions**.

In plain English, Merchant wants only dealTransactions have **provided dates** with Deals.

I tried something like below but it does not work.

```
dates = ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04', '2019-01-05'];


$merchant = Merchant::with(['deals.dealTransactions'])->where('slug', $slug)
                ->whereHas('deals.dealTransactions', function($query) use ($dates) {
                    foreach($dates as $date) {
                        $query->where('date', '=', $date);
                    }                        
                })
                ->first();




deal_transactions table

id, deal_id, date 


deals table 
id, merchant_id, 


merchants table
id, many columns for merchant
```

Thank you

Comment: you only want to load deals which have a dealTransaction date matching the dates, or you only want to load the dealTransaction if it has matching dates?

Comment: @lagbox I want to load both deals and dealTransactions but dealTransactions must be matched with dates.

Comment: thank you, just a little more clarification ... you want to load the deals no matter what, but the dealTransactions from those deals must only be ones that match those dates?

Comment: @lagbox Yes exactly right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a eager load constraint on the nested relationship:

```
$merchant = Merchant::where('slug', $slug)
    ->with(['deals.dealTransactions' => function ($query) use ($dates) {
        $query->whereIn('date', $dates);
    }])->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your schema, this might help:

```
// Here you define the scope that will be used to select & eager load.
$transactionsScope = function ($q) use ($dates) {
    return $q->whereIn('date', $dates);
};
// All merchant of slug in/with that transaction's scope.  
$merchant = Merchant::where('slug', $slug)
    ->whereHas('deals', function ($q) use ($transactionsScope) {
        return $q->whereHas('dealTransactions', $transactionsScope);
    })
    ->with(['deals' => function ($q) use ($transactionsScope) {
        return $q->with('dealTransactions', $transactionsScope);
    }])
    ->firstOrFail();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've got an idea based on your answer. Thanks.